# Highchart x and y axes data from json

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Here is my js fiddle : [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/inchrvndr/ydj4bz4d/2/)

I am plotting differences of timestamps in multiple series reading data from JSON. How to plot "timestamp","timestamp2","timestamp3" against "temperSensorData" instead of steps?

```
  var processed_json = new Array();   //TS1
  var processed_json1 = new Array();  //TS2 

  // Populate initial series
  for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    processed_json.push(data[i].timestamp/1000);
    processed_json1.push(data[i].timestamp2/1000);
  }
```

Comment: Please elaborate your issue

Comment: @AkshayHegde: In my fiddle I am providing only one array as input for series data object. So y axis is dynamically taken to be steps of 1. How do i plot one array against the other? Like tempSensordata for y axis and timestamp for x axis

Comment: ok, create array like this `[ [x0, y0], [x1,y1] ] `,  so that xaxis will be time and y axis will temperature `processed_json.push([data[i].timestamp3/10000000000,parseFloat(data[i].temperSensorData)]);`

Comment: It is hard to understand what you would like to achieve, do you want to get something similar to this jsFiddle? https://jsfiddle.net/ydj4bz4d/3/

Comment: Yes that helped :) @GrzegorzBlachliński